# Pyodbc+Sqlalchemy+MSSQL identifier truncation issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, odbc, pyodbc, freetds

I have a SQL Server 2005 database that I'm trying to access from Python using Sqlalchemy and Pyodbc on Linux. Originally I wrote the script on Windows which worked fine, but when I transfered it to a Centos 6.4 64 bit server I ran into a problem. When doing a query I get the following error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'TBL_WF_DESTINATION.DESTINATION_ID'"
```

I use Sqlalchemy declarative syntax and my query looks like this:

```
destinations = session.query(Destination).all()
```

where `Destination` is a class mapped to an existing table.

A previous query succeeds:

```
models = session.query(Model).all()
```

It seems that somehow Pyodbc has an issue with identifiers longer than 30 characters - 
TBL_WF_DESTINATION.DESTINATION_ID is 33 characters long while TBL_WF_MODEL.MODEL_ID is 21. During some extensive googling, I've come across some references to a 30 character identifier limit - however, it was never mentioned in MSSQL context and all the posts were from a few years ago.
Here is some of my code definitions:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://name:password@dsn')
```

Specifying maximum label length = 30 actually fixes the issue, but I consider it to be a workaround.

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://name:password@dsn', label_length=30)
```

Anything greater than 30 breaks my code.

Here is /etc/freetds.conf

```
[mssql_server]
host = some_ip_addr
port = 1433
tds version = 7.2
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[mssql]
Description     = FreeTDS for MSSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
TDS Version = 7.2
FileUsage = 1
```

~/.odbc.ini

```
[dsn]
Driver=mssql
Description=some description
Server=some_ip_addr
Database=db_name
Port=1433
```

Python 2.7.5, SQLAlchemy 0.8.2, pyodbc 3.0.7, freetds 0.91, unixODBC 2.2.14.

My question is really - what am I doing wrong that I can't use identifiers longer than 30 characters? It seems like a pretty artificial restriction to me. Is there a better way to make it work?

P.S. I can run the same code with a pymssql backend, but it doesn't have the native Decimal type so I'm not using it for that reason.